# STM32F410RB is not outputting the WHOAMI register value of slave MPU9250/6000

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, imu, hal-library

Note: I am beginner :)

I am trying to read the WHOAMI register in the MPU9250/6000 using i2c communication on STM32410RB Nucleo board MCU. I am using `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` to read one byte of data from WHOAMI register in MPU6050 which is supposed to output 104 (0x68) but outputs 216 (I believe this a garbage number). I tried using `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` and `HAL_I2C_Master_Recieve`. But these outputted other garbage numbers.

MPU6050 works fine with ATMEGA328P I2C communication, but I can't seem to get it to work for STM32410RB MCU. I also tried the MPU9250 and another MPU6050 but yielded same results.

Red marks on this picture indicate how I connected the MPU6050 to the nucleo board.

[image]

**Pin out config**

[image: PIN CONFIG]

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
uint8_t snum[5];
uint8_t MPU6050_ADDR = (0x68 << 1);
uint8_t WHO_AM_I_REG = 0x75;
uint8_t PWR_MGMT_1_REG = 0x6B;

  uint8_t pwrmng[2];
  pwrmng[0] = 0x6B;
  pwrmng[1] = 0;

  uint8_t whoami[2];
  uint8_t Data_test;
  HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, pwrmng, 2, 1000);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_Delay(5000);
      HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, WHO_AM_I_REG, 1, &Data_test, 1, 10000);
      sprintf((char*)snum, "%i", Data_test);

      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, snum, strlen((char*)snum), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

CLOCK CONFIG

```
  void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {
      RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
      RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
    
      /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
      */
      __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
      /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
      * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
      */
      RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
      if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
      */
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    
      if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
    }
```

I2C Config

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}
```

UART Communication Config

```
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
    {
    
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */
    
      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */
    
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */
    
      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
      huart2.Instance = USART2;
      huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
      huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
      huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
      huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */
    
      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */
    
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you examine the code in the debugger? Or at least examine the result of I2C calls to know whether they succeed or not, as they will tell you why it did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pinout diagram shows I2C on PB6 and PB7.  But those pins don't go to D14 and D15 on the Nucleo board.  Look at the diagram in the [STM32 Nucleo-64 boards User Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf).  Figure 26 shows the Nucleo-F410RB and PB9 and PB8 are connected to D14 and D15.